# Selecting from Datatable , Grouped by multiple Column with condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a datatable which has 4 fields in it.

```
 ptime, Substation, ColumnTitle, ValueAmount
```

I want to have the row with the maximum ValueAmount , Grouped by Substation and ColumnTitle. So suppose this is my datatable

```
 ptime,  Substation, ColumnTitle, ValueAmount
 --------------------------------------------
 '01:00'    'AA'       'A'          100
 '03:00'    'AA'       'A'          150
 '01:00'    'BB'       'A'          10
 '02:00'    'BB'       'A'          11
 '01:00'    'AA'       'C'          77
 '02:00'    'AA'       'C'          88
 '04:00'    'AA'       'C'          99
```

So I want to have

```
   ptime,  Substation, ColumnTitle, ValueAmount
 --------------------------------------------
 '03:00'    'AA'       'A'          150
 '02:00'    'BB'       'A'          11
 '04:00'    'AA'       'C'          99
```

what is the best linq command for this purpose?
I have programmed this:

```
 var newSort = from row in dtFinal.AsEnumerable()
   group row by new  {Substation = row.Field<string>("Substation"), 
            ColumnTitle= row.Field<string>("ColumnTitle")} into grp       
   select new
   {
     Substation = grp.Key.Substation,
     ColumnTitle = grp.Key.ColumnTitle,         
     ValueAmount = grp.Max(r => decimal.Parse(r.Field<string>("ValueAmount")))
   };
```

but in this syntax I don't have ptime for that. How can I do that.

Thank you

Comment: Btw it's `Column` not `Coulmn`...

Comment: There's no completely straightforward to do this - for a start, if there were rows with the same (maximum) value but different ptime values, which one should be returned? You'll have to do a secondary look-up or join to find the ptime you want.

Comment: @DylanNicholson: SO there is not a way to have it with just one Lookup,is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the group by this value descending to get the "MaxRow", there you find the `ptime`:

```
var newSort = dtFinal.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new
    {
        Substation = row.Field<string>("Substation"),
        ColumnTitle = row.Field<string>("ColumnTitle")
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Substation,
        g.Key.ColumnTitle,
        MaxRow = g.OrderByDescending(row => decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("ValueAmount"))).First()
    })
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        ptime = x.MaxRow.Field<string>("ptime"), // voilà
        x.Substation,
        x.ColumnTitle,
        ValueAmount = decimal.Parse(x.MaxRow.Field<string>("ValueAmount"))
    });
```

---

Since you used query syntax, in this case it's really more readable thanks to the `let`:

```
var newSort = from row in dtFinal.AsEnumerable()
  let xRow = new { Row = row, valueAmount = decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("ValueAmount")) }
  group xRow by new
  {
     Substation = row.Field<string>("Substation"),
     ColumnTitle = row.Field<string>("ColumnTitle")
  } into grp
  let maxRow = grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.valueAmount).First()
  select new
  {
     ptime = maxRow.Row.Field<string>("ptime"),
     grp.Key.Substation,
     grp.Key.ColumnTitle,
     ValueAmount = maxRow.valueAmount
  };
```

Comment: Why do you need the AsEnumerable? Do you know what SQL this generates?

Comment: @DylanNicholson: a `DataTable` has nothing to do with a database and the LINQ provider `Linq-To-DataTable` is actually `Linq-To-Objects` since a `DataTable` is just an in-memory- collection. So no sql is generated. `AsEnumerable` is an extension method which allows to treat a `DataTable` as strongly typed `IEnumerable<DataRow>` even if this old class' `Rows`-property returns a `DataRowCollection` which only implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Well sure if he really did mean that you're absolutely right.  But I'm more curious if your trick can work on a database table.

Comment: @DylanNicholson: if this was Linq-To-Entities(for example) it would stil work. I can't test it though. Of course you have to remove `AsEnumerable`(you see that OP used it?).

Comment: I do,  but I've seen plenty of cases of AsEnumerable being used unnecessarily or with no real understanding of what it means for how much data will be read from a database when using EF.

Comment: @nnmmss: I have edited my answer to show you the same in query syntax(really better in this case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160497/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-dylan-nicholson).

Comment: FWIW, I actually gave this a go using EF core, and it cannot translate those GroupBy constructs into a single query, and ultimately processes all the data locally.

Comment: What query you have used? There is a lot of stuff that's DataTable related like the Field method. That should work, it's just some group by and order by sub queries

Comment: Actually it seems EF Core is very limited in translating any sort of GroupBy calls. EF 6.2 is better, though the query I got didn't actually use GROUP BY and used an OUTER APPLY join to retrieve the ptime values.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using 2 query as below:

```
var dt = from cu in DtFinals
         group cu.ValueAmount by new
            {
                cu.Substation,
                cu.ColumnTitle,
            } into gs
            select new
            {
                Substation = gs.Key.Substation,
                ColumnTitle = gs.Key.ColumnTitle,
                ValueAmount = gs.Max()
            };

var final = from c in DtFinals
            join d in dt on 
            new {c.Substation, c.ColumnTitle,c.ValueAmount} equals 
            new {d.Substation, d.ColumnTitle, d.ValueAmount}
            select new 
            { 
                ptime = c.Ptime, 
                Substation = d.Substation, 
                ColumnTitle = d.ColumnTitle,
                ValueAmount = d.ValueAmount
            };
```